# Java ArrayList multiplication

Tags: java

Hello all I have the following line of code

```
solution first = mylist.remove((int)(Math.random() * mylist));
```

Which give me an error stating

```
The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) double, ArrayList<solution>
```

I am trying to remove a random number in my arrayList from my ArrayList

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: please include the declaration for `mylist`

Comment: @foampile From the error message, `myList` is declared as `ArrayList<solution>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to remove a random element from your list.  To cover all elements with your random index, you need the list size.

It doesn't make sense to multiply a number by an `ArrayList`.  You can't get the size of your list by directly specifying just your list in your code.  Call the `size()` method on your list.  That returns an `int` that can be multiplied.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a random number in within the range of your list size

```
final Random random = new Random();

mylist.remove(random.nextInt(myList.size()));
```

Make sure you create a `Random` and store it as otherwise it may create the same number repeatedly (it is only pseudorandom).

Also, the `nextInt` method excludes the top limit so `mylist.size()` will not return an invalid index.